# How to go to a specific file in Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, grep, directory

I'm trying to follow a walkthrough and this is one of the steps, "go to that same folder in Terminal (if you can't do that you should probably quit now)"  I'm not very familiar with Mac's Terminal, but don't feel like quitting.  If it helps, I need to run a grep -r "what I'm looking for" command on the file.  I really have no idea what I need to do to run that command, but the rest of the walkthrough is pretty thorough, so I know I can follow the next few steps.

Comment: The reason the tutorial told you to stop is, doing stuff the terminal can be very dangerous. Doing a grep is not an issue (yet), but as soon as you're copy-pasting things from some site, you should really consider stopping there, as it might be harmful commands. Can you provide a link to the tutorial in the question? To still provide you with some help: `cd` in the terminal allows to *c*hange *d*irectory.

Comment: I've need to get to an iPhone's restriction passcode (because I forgot it) and here's the steps:

Comment: https://medium.com/@tkunstek/you-can-do-this-without-any-sketchy-russian-tools-674b1a67257a

Answer (score 1):

You need to move to the directory where that file is stored, for this the command is `cd`. For example lets say the file is located in a directory names `MyDir` in the Desktop, the command will be

`cd /Users/{YOUR_USERNAME_HERE}/Desktop/MyDir`

You can run `ls` command here to check if the file is actually present in this directory or not